# Problems Uploading a Visual Studio Project to Google Drive

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, upload, google-drive-api, suo

I'm working on a group project in vb.net on Visual Studio.

Each time I try to upload the project to Google Drive it gives me this error.

[image: There were problems uploading the .suo file, conversion error]

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you zip it before you upload it?

Comment: @MichaelVine Thanks Michael, I've tried uploading it both zipped and unzipped and the same error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off conversion in Settings > General > Convert uploads.

Comment: Than you so much!